# Traffic Offload Using Lipa/Sipto

Tags: lte, 4g

The realization of high data rates in LTE technology over an all IP network means an ever increasing load on packet data networks. 3GPP has defined data offloading as a key solution to cope with this challenge. Data offloading has been a critical area of study in 3GPP Release-10.
Two important traffic offload techniques namely LIPA and SIPTO have been introduced. 
However along with data is it possible to offload voice and SMS traffic as well using LIPA and SIPTO?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to offload voice and **SMS** traffic using a local gateway extension tunnel.

The tunnel is shown in pink on the attached picture as given:

[image]

Please refer to Link for more information ----> [TD S2-096015](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/tsg_sa/WG2_Arch/TSGS2_75_Kyoto/docs/S2-096015.zip).